# Alternative to "separately from"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs

I want to say something like:

> The system stores the crazygonuts data separately from the data feed.

I think this is wrong (maybe I am wrong in that), but I'm not sure exactly why.  One alternative I thought of:

> The system stores the crazygonuts data separate from the data feed.

I checked some dictionaries online, and I did not find separate listed as an adverb, so this also seems incorrect.  I want to keep the verb (stores) in there.  Is there any way I can keep this same sentence structure without sounding silly?  If possible, I would like to use the word separate (or something sufficiently close, like distinctly); or is this formation doomed from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try "apart":

> The system stores the crazygonuts data apart from the data feed.

Or you could re-arrange the sentence:

> The system's crazygonuts data store is separate from the data feed.

Comment: I kind of like the second one, although it does have a slightly different meaning.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with 'separately from'.  I'm not convinced there's anything wrong with 'stores the crazygonuts data (in a location that is) separate from (the location where) the data feed (is stored)'.

Comment: But the word (whatever you choose) refers to thde data not the location.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct, and mean essentially the same thing

Comment: They can't both be right: personally I feel "stored separate from" is a best a different meaning and at worst a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the sentence as it is. *Separately* is a perfectly fine adverb—consider "[married, filing separately](http://www.smartmoney.com/taxes/income/Married-but-Filing-Separately-15597/?zone=intromessage)."

If you must change it, consider *apart*.

Comment: I meant that "separate" is not an adverb.